# Why am I getting "fatal error: SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: arduino-due, softwareserial

I downloaded the Adafruit_GPS library from Adafruit and I'm trying to compile the example code (due_parsing) but I can't seem to get past this silly error:

```
In file included from due_parsing.ino:15:

/Users/haddad/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_GPS/Adafruit_GPS.h:24: fatal error: SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This is the location in the example Arduino Sketch where `SoftwareSerial.h` is mentioned:

```
#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#endif
```

I noticed it's around an `ifdef` guard, so shouldn't it not even matter that I don't have this library?

I went into the .h and .cpp files and commented out the where it called `SoftwareSerial.h`, but I'm still getting that above error.

Does anybody know how to fix this?
I am using Arduino IDE v1.5.5

---

Update:

I didn't put the library in the library direct on my mac but I'm now getting tons of errors, all the errors are with `SoftwareSerial.cpp`. Is anybody else having similar issues when you go to compile?

Comment: You mention you are using a DUE, do you use Arduino IDE 1.5 with it?

Comment: yessir, Arduino IDE v1.5.5

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting after installing the library?

Comment: the errors were all in regards to SoftwareSerial.cpp, but after commenting out those ifdef guards, it worked...for now anyway

Answer (score 3):

According to your comment:

> after commenting out those ifdef guards, it worked

I would say that is a bug in the **Adafruit_GPS** library.

As a matter of fact, the **DUE** is not using the **AVR** architecture (it uses **ARM**), that explains why `#ifdef __AVR__` in `Adafruit_GPS.h` never passes; but then something else should be done specifically for the DUE (missing `#else` or `#elif`).

After checking on *github*, there is an [issue](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GPS-Library/issues/14) open for that; unfortunately, as of April 2014, it has not moved for 10 months.

Your best guess would be to go there and try to "reactivate" this issue.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That library and software for the Due in general seems to be in continual development, not as mature as the stuff out for the AVR boards out there

Answer (score 0):

So I went into the interface file (.h) and removed all references to AVR and then went into (.cpp) and removed all references to AVR there as well. It now seems to be working, although sometimes it says "Not supported Architecture ARM" during compilation...very weird

Answer (score 0):

this is a "bug" in the arduino IDE pre-compilation process.
If you turn on the compiling verbositi in thge precerences menu, you will see that arduino has copied all file (with a rater "stupid" code that just look for include) into a temp folder (wiring lib are not copied, but the below still aplly). Until here, ugly but still fine.

Then, it will -force- compilation of every "included" file, one by one, the facto bypassing the #ifdef.. and this is why you get that problem.

Solution is to heavy change the ide so it will force compilation only in the main, and let the compiler include and compile needed libraries.

I still have no idea why every file is forced, but a change like this is really heavy and break-old-code prone..

Newest IDE to bypass this problem (and also some other problem, like depeency) use a "config" file that will tell the IDE if use the AVR or ARM or x86 library, probabily this file is missing and the ide see te lib as only AVR by default.

Double check if it is really usable on DUE